# Blocking IPs to All Apps But One

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, firewall

I need to allow on U.S. users to connect to our customer web sites (10 of them) but allow all to access our online support ticketing site because we have tech people outside the U.S. that need access to this one site only.

We have a dedicated server running Windows Server 2008 R2.

I was going to run a script to only allow the U.S. IP ranges through Windows Firewall but then I remembered that we have the ticketing site on the same server so if I proceed with the script, I'd be blocking the ticketing site as well.

How can I still only allow U.S. IP ranges on the 10 customer sites but allow everyone on the ticketing site?

We are using IIS 7.5.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that this is the correct approach? Sometimes, through no fault of their own, people end up connecting to sites via IP addresses that are (correctly or incorrectly) "mapped" to non-US locations. Are you sure you want to stop such users from using your sites? IP->Location mappings are a *crude* tool, and I'd recommend their use for e.g. *defaulting* language/region settings, but not for access controls

Answer (score 0):

You can place a check on the `Global.asax` on the BeginRequest.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // here check if is allowed
    if(!IsOnPermitedNetwork(MyCurrentContent.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"])
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        return ;    
    }
}
```

and some utilities functions that you need to make the check.

```
public bool IsOnPermitedNetwork(string sMyIpString)
{
    long TheIpTranslate = AddressToNum(sMyIpString);

    if (TheIpTranslate >= 0)
    {
        // exampple
        // 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
        if (TheIpTranslate >= 3232235520 && TheIpTranslate <= 3232301055)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public long AddressToNum(string cAddress)
{
    IPAddress MyIpToCheck = null;

    if (IPAddress.TryParse(cAddress, out MyIpToCheck))
    {
        return AddressToNum(MyIpToCheck);
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}


public long AddressToNum(IPAddress Address)
{
    byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(Address.Address);

    if (b.Length == 8)
        return (long)(((long)16777216 * b[0]) + ((long)(65536 * b[1])) + ((long)(256 * b[2])) + b[3]);
    else
        return 0;
}
```